# How do I position a span directly under the email input field given this layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to place the span with the id `email-status` directly below the email input field, regardless of the viewport size in order to warn users when email is not correct.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin:300,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Ping coming soon page</title>
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/cdn/friconix.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/logo.svg" class="logo">
        <p class="warning">Your browser does not support SVG. Please update!</p>
      </object>
      <h1>We are launching <span>soon!</span></h1>

      <p>Subscribe and get notified</p>

      <form action="#" method="#" class="email-newsletter-form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address...">
        <span id="email-status">Please enter a valid email</span>
        <button type="submit">Notify Me</button>
      </form>


      <img class="dashboard" src="images/illustration-dashboard.png" alt="Picture of dashboard" />

      <footer>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="#"><i class="fi-xnsuxl-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fi-xnsuxl-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fi-xnsuxl-instagram"></i></a>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; Copyright Ping. All rights reserved.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Libre Franklin", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(16px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  html {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

/* Container */

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5vh 0 0 0;
}

.container .content {
  max-width: 640px;
  max-height: 640px;
}

.container h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #969696;
}

.container h1 span {
  color: #151f29;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container .dashboard {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Form */

form {
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

input[type=email] {
  width: 63%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #c2d3ff;
  color: #c2d3ff;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

input[type=email]::placeholder {
  color: #c2d3ff;
}

input[type=email]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4f7df3;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.8rem 3.5rem;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 15px #c2d3ff;
}

button[type=submit]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  form {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  form input[type=email] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.8rem 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  form button[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  form {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10% 0 20% 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 229px) {
  button[type=submit] {
    padding: 0.3rem 3.5rem;
  }
}

.dashboard {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.error {
  border-color: #a94442;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  color: #969696;
}

footer i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #c2d3ff;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}

footer i:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4f7df3;
  border: 1px solid #4f7df3;
}

footer a {
  color: #4f7df3;
  margin-right: 0.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your button an id like `#button` and use `flex` like this:

```css
.email-newsletter-form {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#button #email {
     flex: 1 1 0;
}

#email-status {
     order: 3;
}
```

For mobile devices and smaller viewports use `media queries` like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #email-status {
      order: 0;
   }
}
```